# JavaScript: Is there an equivalent to the Python setattr() function?

Tags: javascript, class, attributes, instance-variables

I have a class to which I would like to include a method of overriding some of the default instance variables in the constructor, without having a dozen parameters.  I would like to do this by passing an object in the form of:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(overrides) {
        this.instanceVar1 = default1;
        this.instanceVar2 = default2,

        for (key in overrides) {
           this.key = overrides[key];
        }
    }

let overrides = {instanceVar1 : value,
                 instanceVar2 : value2};
let instance = new MyClass(overrides);

console.log(instance.instanceVar1)  // Outputs value, not default1.
```

In Python this could be done with

```
if overrides is not None:
    for key, value in overrides.items():
        self.setattr(self, key, value)
```

Is there a JS equivalent or do I just have to add a bunch of parameters with default values?

Comment: `this[key] = overrides[key];` You just need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) to access a variable property. A common pattern though is to `Object.assign` the passed `overrides` over a default object and proceed from there.

Comment: @pilchard Thanks, that worked.  I figured it was something obvious, but I've been writing everything in dot notation for the last 3 days and forgot I could use the bracket notation in JS for instance properties.    `Object.assign` doesn't work for what I was doing as some of the overrides are being used when instantiating additional objects (of other classes) in my constructor, but that I will keep that in my toolbox for later.
  
  If you submit your response as an answer, I'll go ahead and mark it as the Correct answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your given example you simply need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) to access a property from a variable.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(overrides) {
    this.instanceVar1 = 'default1';
    this.instanceVar2 = 'default2';

    for (const key in overrides) {
      this[key] = overrides[key];
      //   ^^^
    }
  }
}

let overrides = {
  instanceVar1: 'value',
  instanceVar2: 'value2'
}
let instance = new MyClass(overrides);

console.log(instance.instanceVar1); // value
```

An alternative would be to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) the needed parameters from the `overrides` object setting appropriate defaults, and leaving the `...rest` for use elsewhere.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor({
    instanceVar1 = 'default1',
    instanceVar2 = 'default2',
    ...overrides
  }) {
    this.instanceVar1 = instanceVar1;
    this.instanceVar2 = instanceVar2;

    console.log(overrides); // { extraVar1: 'another value' }
  }
}

let overrides = {
  instanceVar1: 'value',
  instanceVar2: 'value2',
  extraVar1: 'another value'
}
let instance = new MyClass(overrides);

console.log(instance.instanceVar1); // value
```